# How to make live search on an Div with input filter

Tags: javascript, html

I have some troubles with a live search script.

I want to make it when i type some in my search input to hide **div** that not contains this text in search input. My code so far.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
<div id="Container">
<div  data-name="Anni">
Anni
</div>
<div  data-name="Pedro">
Pedro
</div>
<div data-name="Tomi">
Tomi
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
  var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
  $('#Container').show().not(function(){
      return matcher.test($(this).find('data-name').text())
  }).hide();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to search through the `children()` of the container and use `filter()` instead of `not()`

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
  var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
  $('#Container').children().hide().filter(function(){
      return matcher.test($(this).text())
  }).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
<div id="Container">
  <div data-name="Anni">
    Anni
  </div>
  <div data-name="Pedro">
    Pedro
  </div>
  <div data-name="Tomi">
    Tomi
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On my own I can offer a solution using the `each()` method.

```js
$("#box").on('keyup', function(){
  let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();  
  $('#Container div[data-name]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" />
      <div id="Container">
        <div data-name="Anni">
          Anni
        </div>
        <div data-name="Pedro">
          Pedro
        </div>
        <div data-name="Tomi">
          Tomi
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```